# Remove or delete elements

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have the following list:

```
i=2
k=3
 list = Tuples[Tuples[{0, 1}, i], k]

{{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0,0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}}
```

I would like to remove redundant element, like "{{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}" since they have the same value like "{{1, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}". The "{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}" element should be removed as well. Elements like "{{1, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}" are not equal to "{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}}" though. Note that the inner subsets are of size $i$ which are elements in subsets of size $k$.

Maybe the list should be created differently? How can I make this happen? The goal is to get it for any $i$ and $k$ in general.

For example, instead of

```
list = Tuples[Tuples[{0, 1}, 2], 2]
{{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 
   1}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 
   1}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 
   0}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 
   1}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}}
```

a possible output is:

```
{{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 
   0}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 
   1}, {1, 1}}}
```

Comment: Please show your desired output.

Comment: @PaulCommentary added an example, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
With[{i = 2, k = 3},
 DeleteCases[
  Tuples[DeleteDuplicatesBy[Tuples[{0, 1}, i], Sort], k],
  ConstantArray[0, {k, i}]
 ]]
```

Result:

```
{{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 
   1}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 
   1}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 
   0}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0,
    1}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 
   1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0,
    0}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 
   1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 0}, {1,
    1}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 
   1}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {0,
    1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}}
```

For the 2,2 case, the result is:

```
{{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 
   1}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 
   1}, {1, 1}}}
```

... which is the same as your expected output, if you're willing to apply `Map[Sort,expected,{2}]` to change `{1,0}` into `{0,1}`

Comment: Beautiful @flinty, just how do I apply the Map[Sort,expected,{2}] is I need to? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean? I only put that in in case you're worried about the order in each sub-sub-list. You could do `Map[Reverse,result,{2}]` if you want the results in the same order too.

Comment: The "Reverse" fixed it. Thank you so much.